# How do I put max and min limit on Django Admin Table's float fields?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a `Details` model as below:

```
class Detail(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    skype_session_attendance = models.FloatField()
    internal_course_marks = models.FloatField()
    programming_lab_activity = models.FloatField()
    mid_term_marks = models.FloatField()
    final_term_marks = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username}-{self.subject}'
```

I want the Admin Panel to have the min and max limit on all the Float Fields, such as, when Admin try to enter the values through Admin Panel in the Detail's Table float fields, he/she should not be allowed to enter the values except within the range of min and max limit.

Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Validators , like this :

```
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator

min = 0
max = 10
skype_session_attendance = models.FloatField(
    validators=[MinValueValidator(min), MaxValueValidator(max)],
)
```

Comment: thanks and what about the labels and help_text in the Admin Panel? How do I show/change these?

Comment: for the help text you can do this ------------ ( help_text = " please enter here " ) ------------- and for label -------------- ( verbose_name = " your label " ) ------------------- if my solution works for you i will be grateful if u vote it and mark it as best answer

Comment: Yes, I will mark it once I will test it. Right now I am preparing the documentation, it might take me an hour or two to finish the docs.